# Implementing redux in React Native app not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get a small app to run in react native with redux. It was running without redux but since I have tried to add redux to it, it is no longer running (it displays a blank white screen and says). I'm trying to stare clear of classes and do it in a functional way:

> Lodaing 100% (572/572)

I think I'm linking up the redux store to my main app component incorrectly.

Here is the main app component where I try to link it to redux:

**index.ios.js:**

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { createStore, Provider } from 'redux'
import { Volcalc } from './app/components/volcalc/Volcalc'
import { width } from './app/components/width/width.reducer'
import React from 'react'

const initialState = Map({ 'width1': 20, 'width2': 0, 'width3': 0 })
const store = createStore(width, initialState)

const updateWidth = (text, number) => {
  store.dispatch(this.state, {
    type: 'UPDATE_WIDTH',
    payload: {
      number: number,
      value: text
    }
  })
}

export const App = () => {
  console.log(store.getState)
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Volcalc
        updateWidth={updateWidth}
        state={store.getState()}
      />
    </Provider>
  )
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('volcalc_m', () => App)
```

Here is the Volcalc component which is inside the app component:

**Volcalc.js:**

```
import { View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Width } from '../width/Width'

export const Volcalc = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Width updateWidth={props.updateWidth} />
    </View>
  )
}

const $mainColor = '#00d1b2'
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 0.5,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: $mainColor
  }
}
```

And the width component which is inside the Volcalc component:

**width.js:**

```
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export const Width = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Width1"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        onChangeText={text => props.updateWidth(text, 1)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Width2"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        onChangeText={text => props.updateWidth(text, 2)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Width3"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        onChangeText={text => props.updateWidth(text, 3)}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = {
  input: {
    margin: 15,
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
    borderColor: 'grey',
    borderWidth: 1
  },
}
```

This is the only reducer. It is called in `index.ios.js`:

**width.reducer.js:**

```
// @flow
import { Map } from 'immutable'

let initialMap = Map({ 'width1': 20, 'width2': 0, 'width3': 0 })

export const width = (state: Map<*, *> = initialMap, action: Object) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_WIDTH': {
      let newState = state
        .set('width' + action.payload.number, action.payload.value)
      return newState
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

First issue is that you do `import { createStore, Provider } from 'redux'`. There is no such thing as `Provider` in redux library. It's only in `react-redux` library.

This is the official statement from the react-redux library:

**Provider store**

> Makes the Redux store available to the connect() calls in the component hierarchy below. Normally, you can’t use connect() without wrapping the root component in

So, you do NOT need to wrap Volcalc component with the Provider at all as you do not connect any components below it. Right? (Altough I would recommend you to use connect & Provider anyway).

Second issue is that you call dispatch in a wrong way. What did you want to say with `store.dispatch(this.state, ...)`? There is **only one argument for dispatch function** - that is the action itself.

Replace your index.ios.js with the following code and you are good to go.

**index.ios.js**

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { createStore, Provider } from 'redux'
import { Volcalc } from './app/components/volcalc/Volcalc'
import { width } from './app/components/width/width.reducer'
import React from 'react'

const initialState = Map({ 'width1': 20, 'width2': 0, 'width3': 0 })
const store = createStore(width, initialState)

const updateWidth = (text, number) => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATE_WIDTH',
    payload: {
      number: number,
      value: text
    }
  })
}

export const App = () => {
  console.log(store.getState)
  return (
    <Volcalc
      updateWidth={updateWidth}
      state={store.getState()}
    />
  )
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('volcalc_m', () => App)
```

Hope this helped. :-)